# Git Merge: Can we merge and include messages in Git Bash itself?

Tags: git, command-line, version-control, git-merge, git-bash

Simple quesiton. Is it possible to write my message in git bash directly like when we commit rather than through a text editor?

To be honest, it feels unnecessary to be opening a text editor every time.

Any reason for it to rely on a text editor rather than through git bash itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes!

```
git merge <branch> -m message
```

see full documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)

Comment: Okay. I probably should have at least tested this before asking haha.